# Google Drive - Avoid complete file download if changes detected

Tags: python, google-drive-api, synchronization, pydrive

Suppose user has granted an access to my app which can access user drive. And user imported a drive file in our website by using [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/), and that file is now also stored on our server. [Webhooks](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch) are set to detect future changes to that file. Lets suppose content of a file is changed in Google Drive. I don't want to download the complete file again. Is there a way to only download what has been changed and update the existing file?

Comment: no. There might be something in the Realtime API you can use

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to just download the portion of the content that's changed. However, you can inspect the `X-Goog-Changed` header that Google sends along in the request. You will only need to download the file again if the value is "content". More information on the [Push Notifications developer guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push).